# Beamer: change size of figure caption

Tags: beamer, captions, fontsize

I am creating a `beamer` presentation and I would like to change the size of the caption under the figures. I am using the `Madrid` theme.

I tried the obvious way:

```
\caption{\scriptsize{Text of the caption.}}
```

and

```
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}
```

in the preamble of the document.

However none of that seems to have any effect.

Comment: I'd like to see an example showing that `\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}` doesn't have any effect.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: right, that works for me, except that I can't multiply the size. I'd like `0.7\scriptsize`, but that actually prints "0.7" before every caption...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the caption package: `\usepackage{caption}`

Then use captionsetup:
`\captionsetup{font=scriptsize,labelfont=scriptsize}`

Have fun with LaTeX!

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get an "undefined control sequence" error.

Comment: You have to use the package 'caption' \usepackage{caption}

Comment: Also, you can restrict this to figures by using the 'figure' option `\captionsetup[figure]{font=scriptsize,labelfont=scriptsize}`.

Comment: That doesn't do anything. @samcarter's suggestion though works!

Answer (score 27):

To change the font size your second command

```
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}
```

should work fine. In case you'd like "non-standard" font sizes, you can use

```
\setbeamerfont{caption}{series=\normalfont,size=\fontsize{20}{24}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personnally use `\usepackage[textfont={small,it}]{caption}` in the preamble.
So in your case, you may try `\usepackage[textfont={scriptsize}]{caption}`